# How to increment a variable in Lisp

Tags: lisp, autolisp

Here's the problem in the code:

```
    (foreach n l_pt
        (write-line
            (strcat "sommet" str_sep
                (itoa (setq (nbs (+1 nbs )))) str_sep
                (rtos (car n) 2 2) str_sep
                (rtos (cadr n) 2 2) str_sep
                (strcat "2") str_sep
                (strcat "borne")
            )
            f_open
        )
    )
    ;;(write-line "" f_open)
```

I have these kind of files in output:

> Sommets;;
>
> Type;Num;X;Y;Precison;Nature
>
> sommet;1;1532292.16;3214140.11;2;borne
>
> sommet;2;1532287.08;3214140.60;2;borne
>
> sommet;1;1532291.45;3214136.43;2;borne
>
> sommet;2;1532286.50;3214135.87;2;borne
>
> sommet;1;1532287.08;3214140.60;2;borne

As you've guessed, the problematic part is the "Num" which is not working as intended, incrementing.

I've understood that it's this line: "    (itoa (setq (nbs (+1 nbs )))) str_se" not working as intended, but I don't know why. I've tried to switch it to (setq (nbs (+ 1 nbs))), but it doesn't works either.

Do you have any ideas from where it's coming?

[Complete code](http://pastebin.com/R34w5hKw)

Comment: Does `(+ 1 nbs)` do *exactly* the same thing as `(+1 nbs)`?

Comment: Forms in languages in the Lisp family are generally written as `(operator arg1 arg2 ...)`.  In the case of `setq`, the assignment operator, the argument is order is `(setq <place> <new value>)`.  That means that `(setq (nbs (+1 nbs)))` is wrong, and should be `(setq nbs (+ 1 nbs))`.

Comment: Good catch, @Joshua.  When you're used to languages that take function params in `()`, it's easy to miss this kind of thing.  You might want to post that as an answer.  (As an aside, it's possible that `+1` is a defined incrementer function and that `(+1 nbs)` returns the same value as `(+ 1 nbs)`.  However the latter form is clearly correct.)

Comment: @juan I was not sure whether +1 was a function in autolisp. In common lisp it is named 1+, probably because +1 is legal syntax for a number.  I didn't post thatas an answer because if that is the solution, then this is just a typo problem.

Comment: @Joshua and Juan, Thanks for your responses  ! 

Well `(+1 nbs)` was a typo in the initial message. When I do it, it writed nothing in the output file.

I corrected as you prescripted, I now have `(itoa (setq nbs (+ 1 nbs)))`, which doesn't have the same output. Now, each Num in the column section is 1, it doesn't switch between 1 and 2 anymore.

It seems more logical, even if I still does not underestand how that's working. "Itoa" convert the value returned by the function "setq", which should be nbs + 1 ?

Anyway, thanks for answering.

Comment: Just in case, please post the complete revised code

Comment: @Feldur Sure, here is it : [link](http://pastebin.com/R34w5hKw)

Comment: Can you check what happens with a minimal example like this one?  `(defun test (/ counter) (foreach n '(a b c) (write-line (itoa (setq counter (+ 1 counter))))))`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're just off by one parenthesis. Or that you need to initialize `nbs` outside the repeat. It depends on how you want it to work.

It looks like your code (greatly simplified) is this:

```
;; Stuff before the problem
(repeat (sslength js)
    ;; (setq....)
    (setq nbs 0)
    ;;; Lots of stuff
    (foreach n l_pt
        ;; The printing code including...
        (setq nbs (+ 1 nbs))
    )
)
```

As you can see, you're setting `nbs` to `0` each time you go through the `repeat` loop and then adding `1` to it later.

It looks like you wanted to separate those loops - `repeat` until finished calculating the information, and then `foreach` to print out the whole list `l_pt`.

As it stands, I think you're only appending 1 line of information to `l_pt` each time through the big `repeat` loop and only printing that one item from the `foreach` statement.

Moving a parenthesis would give you this:

```
(repeat (sslength js)
    ;;...
    (setq nbs 0)
    ;;...
)
(foreach n l_pt
    ;;...
    (setq nbs (+ 1 nbs))
)
```

You could also place the `(setq nbs 0)` outside the repeat loop. That would probably be best either way so that it's clear what you're doing and there's no need to initialize it 5+ times...

Also, this shows why it's a good idea to clearly separate your variable assignments. They can get lost at the end of a long `(setq`) statement:

```
;; Do this,
(setq sentence "This is one or more variable assignments."
      number 200)

;; or this,
(setq sentence "This is one or more variable assignments.")
(setq number 200)

;; not this.
(setq sentence "This is one or more variable assignments." number 200)
```

Anyway, either of those options should get your counter `nbs` working again.

Hope that helps!

P.S. Just to help with the (+1 nbs) discussion in the comments above, the following are all correct and equivalent in AutoLISP:

```
(+ 1 nbs)
(+ nbs 1)         ;; Order is not important for addition
(+ nbs 1 0 0 0)   ;; Any number of values can be added
(1+ nbs)          ;; The typical way to increment a value
                  ;; (1+ is a function that returns the value + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be something peculiar to [AutoLISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoLISP). I say that because this code (adapted to [Common Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) as you'll see)

```
(defun foo (l_pt)
  (let ((str_sep ";")
        (nbs 0))

    (mapcar #'(lambda (n) (write-line (strcat (list "sommet" str_sep
                                                    (itoa (setq nbs (+ 1 nbs))) str_sep
                                                    (rtos (car n) 2 2) str_sep
                                                    (rtos (cadr n) 2 2) str_sep
                                                    (strcat "2") str_sep
                                                    (strcat "borne")))
                                      ))
            l_pt)))

(defun rtos (a b c) (strcat a))

(defun strcat (string-designators)
  (with-output-to-string (strcat)
    (cond ((listp string-designators)
           (mapcar #'(lambda (s) (princ s strcat)) string-designators))
          (t (princ string-designators strcat)))))

(defun itoa (i) (write-to-string i))
```

for this expression:

```
(foo '((x y) (a b) (aa bb)))
```

produces this output:

```
sommet;1;X;Y;2;borne
sommet;2;A;B;2;borne
sommet;3;AA;BB;2;borne
```

Admittedly, I had to change many things to accommodate elements of AutoLISP that aren't in Common Lisp, perhaps the most significant of which is I didn't write an equivalent of foreach (because there's no way to know I'd replicate its idiosyncrasies), but nevertheless it at least appears `setq` is doing what you expect.